Proving the Product of Zeros of the Function $ f(x) = \frac{e^x}{x} - \ln x + x - a $ is Less Than 1
Given $$ f(x) = \frac{e^x}{x} - \ln x + x - a $$,
prove that if $ f(x) $ has two zeros $ x_1 $ and $ x_2 $, then $ x_1 x_2 < 1 $.
I am looking for a mathematical proof or an intuitive explanation that sheds light on why this product of zeros is always less than $1$. Any insights or detailed steps to arrive at the proof would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!
My Thoughts
This function resembles an upward-opening parabola. It can be shown that its extremum occurs at $ x = 1 $ since $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}(e^x+x)(x-1)$.

I think you are Chinese, so you can find the answer here.

Also, you can find many videos may help in BiliBili

Minimum value is negative, when $x=1$. f(1) is positive. We can prove  $\lim_{ x \to 0} f(x)=+\infty$ to show that both roots are less than $1$. I'm not sure, but this is supposed to work

@Gwen If there are two roots, one is greater than 1 and the other is less than 1. So you must show that if $x_0$ is a root greater than 1, then the other root $x_2$ must satisfy $0<x_2<\frac{1}{x_0}$

Set $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$, $f(x)=\tfrac{e^x}{x}-\ln x+x-a$. Then $f'(x)=\frac{xe^x-e^x}{x^2}-\tfrac{1}{x}+1=\tfrac{(e^x+x)(x-1)}{x^2}$. So $f'(x)=0$ can only happen when $x=1$. In particular, since $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$, it follows that $f$ attains it minimum at $1$.
$f(1)=1+e-a$, so if $a\leq 1+e$, then clearly $f$ will have at most $1$ root. So we can assume $a>1+e$ and in this case $f$ will clearly have exactly two roots, $x_1<1$ and $x_2>1$.
We want to show $x_1 x_2<1$, which means that $x_2<\tfrac{1}{x_1}$. In other words, it suffices to show that $f\big(\tfrac{1}{x_1}\big)>0$ since this will guarantee that $x_2\in\big(1,\tfrac{1}{x_1}\big)$.
This allows us to reformulate the problem. Assume $a>1+e$ and assume that $b\in(0,1)$ is a root of $f$. Prove that $f\big(\tfrac{1}{b})>0$.
But $f\big(\tfrac{1}{b}\big)=be^{1/b}+\ln b+\tfrac{1}{b}-a$ and since $f(b)=0$, we can write $a=\tfrac{e^b}{b}-\ln b+b$. So we need to show that $be^{1/b}-\tfrac{e^b}{b}+2\ln b+\tfrac{1}{b}-b>0$.
Define $g:(0,1)\to\mathbb R$, $g(x)=xe^{1/x}-\tfrac{e^x}{x}+2\ln x+\tfrac{1}{x}-x$. Clearly $\lim_{x\to 1} g(x)=0$, so it suffices to show that $g$ is decreasing. After some simplifications, $g'(x)=\big(e^{1/x}-\tfrac{e^x}{x}\big)\big(1-\tfrac{1}{x}\big)-\tfrac{(x-1)^2}{x^2}$, so it suffices to show that on $(0,1)$ we have that $xe^{1/x}>e^x$, which is equivalent to $e^{1/x-x}>\tfrac{1}{x}$ and therefore to $\tfrac{1}{x}-x>-\ln x$.
Define $h:(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ by $h(x)=\tfrac{1}{x}-x+\ln x$. We need that $h>0$ and clearly $\lim_{x\to 1} h(x)=0$, so again it suffices to show that $h$ is decreasing on the domain. But $h'(x)=-\tfrac{x^2-x+1}{x^2}=-\tfrac{(x-1/2)^2}{x^2}-\tfrac{3}{4}<0$.
